# How does one obtain Hesse normal form of plane equation?

Tags: analytic-geometry, vectors

We have been studying the Hesse normal form of the plane equation, but the sketch of the plane in space given by the lecturer was horrible.

Basically I ask you to explain me how does one obtain the Hesse normal form equation geometrically.

Also I need clearing up on the question of,why is the unit  vector n0 of vector normal to the plane equal to cosines of the  angles with axes.

Once again I do not need the process of conversion from general cartesian form into Hesse form, I need geometric as well as intuitive explanation.

Hope I was clear enough because the resources on the subject on the Web are quite scarce.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here goes,self answer QA style baby.

First introduce some notation :

Let P be our plane

Let $\bar n$ be vector orthogonal to plane and let $d=|\bar n|$

Let $M\in P$ be arbitrary point M(x,y,z),let $\bar r$ be position vector of point M

Let $pr_x y = \frac{x \dot y}{|y|}$ be projection of y onto x

Let $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ be angles that $\bar n $ makes with x,y,z axes respectively

Now we can consider the unit vector $\bar n_0$ and we can conclude that

$cos(i,\bar n_0 ) = cos \alpha = \frac{i \bar n_0}{|i||\bar n_0|}= \frac{pr_i \bar n_0}{|\bar n_0|} = pr_i \bar n_0$

Same for beta and delta,thus we can conclude that $\bar n_0 = \langle cos \alpha , cos\beta,cos \gamma \rangle$

Now we can consider the point L at distance d from the origin(connected with origin by orthogonal vector)

Then triangle OLM is right triangle and thus $pr_{ \bar n} \bar r$ is equal to d and from this conclusion we obtain the form in following steps:

$$pr_{\bar n} \bar r = \frac{\bar r \bar n }{|n|} = \frac{d \bar r \bar n_0}{d|\bar n_0|}=d$$

$$\bar r \bar n_0 = d$$

And that is the way its done