# How to compute Hesse normal form of plane equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, analytic-geometry, 3d

I was studying  [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943423/how-does-one-obtain-hesse-normal-form-of-plane-equation)  but it doesn't provide me with what I need.

Say I give you this plane's equation:

$x + y - z + 2 = 0$

Is my goal to obtain $-1$ instead of the $2$? I usuall see square roots in Hesse normal form, so I believe you multiply a vector by its length?

Can someone guide me through this calculation, step-by-step?

Comment: What exactly are you calculating?

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the Hesse normal form of the above equation for the plane.